# How to use Count over multiple fields in django?

Tags: django, django-models

How to use `Count` over many fields in Django? How to count row only if given multiple columns are unique?
For example for a model below.

```
class ProductViewed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             blank=True, null=True, related_name="viewed")
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="views")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.product)} viewed on {self.created_at}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at', )
        verbose_name_plural = "ProductViewed"
```

I want to achieve followings. Count based on `user_id`, `ip_address`, `created_at__day`. Is there any way to do so?

Currently I could achieve the following

```
Product.objects.annotate(vcount=Count('views__ip_address'))
```

Comment: Counting over relations usually means that rows where no related objects exist will not be in the result - are you okay with `Product`s that have no related `ProductViewed` objects not being returned in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to join all the fields that you want to perform the unique count on together using [`Concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) and then counting on the result. The [`Trunc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) function is good for extracting part of a datetime

```
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc, Concat

Product.objects.annotate(
    view_day=Trunc('views__created_at', 'day')
).annotate(
    user_ip_and_day=Concat('views__user_id', 'views__ip_address', 'view_day', output_field=models.CharField())
).annotate(
    vcount=models.Count('user_ip_and_day')
)
```

Comment: Your answer has almost solved what I wanted. Let me check again and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
Product.objects.annotate(vcount=Count('views__ip_address')).annotate(ucount=Count('views__user_id')).annotate(ccount=Count('views__created_at__day'))
```